# Reading and writing file to PHP, help with formatting?

Tags: php, string, file

I'm writing this to a file:

```
    $myFile = "purchases.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
    $stringData = $title ."|". $id;
        fwrite ($fh, $stringData."|");
    fclose ($fh);
```

In a separate file i'm writing the names:

```
  $name = $_POST['name'];
    $last = $_POST['lastname'];
    $name = $name ." ". $last;
    $myFile = "purchases.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
    $stringData = $name;
    fwrite ($fh, $stringData."\r\n");
    fclose ($fh);
```

And echo-ing the contents:

```
foreach($lines as $theline ) {
            list($title, $id, $name) = split('\|',$theline); 
                    echo "
                        <tr><td><h3>Title</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>ID</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Name</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Date</h3></td>
                         <tr><td><h4>$title</h4></td>
                         <td><h4>$id</h4></td>
                         <td><h4>$name</h4></td>
                         <td><h4>".date('l \\t\h\e jS')."</h4></td></tr>
                         ";                  
                     }
```

File looks like this:

```
 Uncharted 3 |1| Deus Ex |2| Metal Gear Solid |3|Lib drfsdgf
```

Problem: If there's more than one game title in the file, it prints the title in place of the customer name to the table.

Comment: you have to determine format first. any reason you're using this one with more that one game on line?

Comment: It's meant for a purchase history page, so I wanted list if users bought more than one game.

Comment: its much better to store such info in a database. you will get whatever statistics you want with just one query. Any reason you don't want to use a database?

Comment: I know it's much better, but these are the requirements :s

Comment: it's not requirements but merely a whim. I myself won't waste my time trying to make a flat file doing database job.

Comment: Just curious, what's relation between a game and a name? What are these separate files writing into your poorchases.txt?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel after a user purchases a game, they input their name so i can track them on the purchases history. one file adds game title, and ID and the other adds the name of the user to purchases as well. it's not complex

Comment: you have to write it at once, not in separate files

Answer (score 2):

Consider storing your data in json or xml format.  Then, when you read it out, you can use built-in php functions to read it correctly.

`json_encode` and `json_decode` are your friends.

Edit:  Above advice still applies, but I just noticed the 2 different files aspect.

This solution won't work as well, since you're adding to the data twice.  Either clean up the way you add the data to your file (fully build the string, then write it to your file), or switch to a database.  Databases are designed to handle problems like this much more gracefully.

Comment: The data is only supposed to be accessed through a file, is there not another way?

Comment: to parse such a format is not a big deal. thousands sites works with it, and feel all right without lame built-in php functions. in fact, XML would be way more problematic in terms of parsing and writing

Comment: json_encode will store your string in a specific format.  When you read the data back out, json_decode will turn it into a php object or array.

Comment: Storing the information in a database would be even less problematic and eliminate the fundamental raciness of using flat text files.

Comment: @someone: to explain what Toast is recommending, he's basically recommending that you continue to store the data in the same flat file, but instead of formatting it like "{$title} |{$id}|", he's suggesting you store it like this: `json_encode(array('title' => $title, 'id' => $id)) . "\n"`. Then when you retrieve the data, you can simply do this: `foreach ($lines AS $theline) { $game = json_decode($theline); }`

Comment: I think you saw my comment prior to me editing it. :) Edit: and then I posted this prior to me seeing your edit. :)

Comment: @Michael is dead on.  The point is to change the format you store the data in, so that you can specifically reference name, title, etc.  This also helps to future-proof it, as you can add more fields (say a score) without breaking old entries.  

Your current system relies heavily on data always being in a given order, which breaks if the order changes (as you saw with multiple titles).  Instead of suggesting a hack to work around this, I suggest trying to work out the root of the problem.